# How to store directory path in the DB?

Tags: database, path, directory

I'm trying to store directory path in the database (as we'll be using them in our project very often) and stuck on a question - which way of storing directory paths is more favorable:

1. `/my/directory/path/` - with an ending slash
2. `/my/directory/path` - without an ending slash
3. `my/directory/path`
4. something else?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes no difference. Choose one and stick with it.

So long as your path handling routines handle the data the same way, you will be fine.